# why does the ctor for my class derived from SecurityTokenParameters get called so many times

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to implement a custom token in my WCF service application, mostly this is copied from the sample at MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872.aspx

Why does the constructor for my class derived from `SecurityTokenParameters` get called so many times?  It makes it a real chore to debug. Is this supposed to happen or have I done something wrong?

Thanks